# need help creating function in C that gives out specific amount of \n

Tags: c, function

This is how my code looks right now:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_lines(int n); 

int main() {
printf("%i", print_lines(7));
return 0;
}

void print_lines(int n) {
    int i;
    scanf("%i", &n);
    for (i = 1; n != 0; --1) 
        printf("\n");
}
```

The aim is that the function prints out as many new lines as the user puts in with the scan f function. 
what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you clarify further? I cannot exactly understand what you mean in the last line.

Comment: yeah, so the thing the function should do is print out as many new lines (\n) as the user of the program puts in via the scanf function. so in that case above it should be 7 new lines

Comment: In the main function, you should just call the function like this: print_lines(7); not pass it as an argument to printf function. Also, what is --1 supposed to mean in the cycle in print_lines function?

Comment: Also, in the print_line function should be just the for cycle, not the scanf. Something like: for(i=0; i<n; i++) {printf("/n");}

Comment: What's the meaning of `printf("%i", print_lines(7));` when function `print_lines` does not (and is not supposed to) return anything? What exactly are you trying to achieve by that???

Comment: yeah I see know that the printf function is nonsense. thanks guys.

Comment: this line: `for (i = 1; n != 0; --1) ` is also nonsense.  Perhaps you meant: `for( int i=0; i<n; i++ )`

Comment: the `printf()` function is mighty large and CPU cycles expensive for outputting a newline.  Perhaps you might want to use: `putchar( '\n' );`

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you wish:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_lines(int n); 

int main() {
print_lines(7);
return 0;
}

void print_lines(int n) {
    int i;
    for (i = n; i >= 1; --i) 
        printf("\n");
}
```

- If the return type of `print_lines` is `void`, you cannot use it in an expression as if you were using its value.
- If you are passing a value (`7`) to the function, then you need not read it again using `scanf`.
- If you are already printing in `print_lines`, then you need not use `printf` in `main`. Just the function call is enough.
- `for (i = 1; n != 0; --1)` won't get you anywhere. This line alone has too many errors. You are initializing `i`, testing for `n` and incrementing `1` (which is not possible in C).

Try reading some basics for better understanding.

Another "trick" might be:

```
printf("%.*s\n", 7, "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
```

This would print the first 7 characters from the string of 20 characters given as third argument.

Comment: Why the scanf in print_lines function?

Comment: @StoryTeller: I am introducing slightest modifications in the original code OP has given. There is room for a lot of other improvements too.

Comment: I feel `i > 0` would be nicer then `i >= 1`.

Comment: thanks man I think I understand what I did wrong now. Just started to learn so Im still struggling a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I think a better implementation of what you're trying to get at is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_lines(int n); 

int main() {
    /* take input here (how many lines etc) */
    print_lines(7));
    return 0;
}

void print_lines(int n) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) 
        printf("\n");
}
```

The variant where you want to use inside of printf would be the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_lines(int n); 

int main() {
    /* take input here (how many lines etc) */
    char* lines = print_lines(7);
    printf("%s", lines);
    free(lines) // <-- important
    return 0;
}

char* print_lines(int n) {
    int i;
    char* res = malloc(sizeof(char) * (n + 1)); // <-- important, for \0 termination
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) 
        res[i] = '\n';
    res[n] = '\0';
    return res;
}
```

However I'd rather use a more generic approach, where you can get N of any character supplied to the function as a secondary parameter. I'll leave that part to you.

EDIT: Here's a version with a user-created buffer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_lines(int n); 

int main() {
    /* take input here (how many lines etc) */
    char buf[8]; // if you use GCC you can use char buf[N], these are variable length arrays, if not, use a similar malloc method above
    print_lines(7, buf);
    printf("%s", buf);
    return 0;
}

void print_lines(int n, char buf[]) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        buf[i] = '\n';
    buf[n] = '\0';
}
```

And finally, the fantasy solution StoryTeller suggested:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void most_generic_printN(int n, char c, FILE* f) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        fprintf(f, "%c", c);
}

int main() {
    most_generic_printN(10, 'a', stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

In the above solution, stdout is the standard output stream, which is what you see as the console. You can redirect this to be a file and such. Play around with it!

Comment: There's also the variant of making the OP pass the buffer (to avoid dynamic allocation); as well as possibly passing a `FILE*` to generalize over `printf`.

Comment: Surely there are many variants. But for now these variants will occupy the OP for a good enough time it seems.

Comment: Well, it was you who opened the door for a discussion of variants :)

Comment: Sure, I love to present many other options. Maybe I'll get to adding them as well. Would keep the post complete.

Answer (score 0):

"While N goes to 0, print a newline."

```
void print_lines(int n)
{
    while (n --> 0) printf("\n");
}
```